# Bases of three $n$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^{2n}$ which have pairwise trivial intersection.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, contest-math

This problem is from the [Simon Marias Mathematics Competition](https://www.simonmarais.org/2023.html) (Paper B) which was conducted on October 14, 2023.

**The statement** (verbatim):

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three $n$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^{2n}$ with the property that $A \cap B = B \cap C = C \cap A =\{\mathbf 0\}$. Prove that there exist bases $\{\mathbf a_1, \mathbf a_2, \ldots, \mathbf a_n\}$ of $A$, $\{\mathbf b_1,\mathbf b_2, \ldots , \mathbf b_n\}$ of $B$ and $\{\mathbf c_1, \mathbf c_2, \ldots ,\mathbf c_n\}$ of $C$ with the property that for each $i \in\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, the vectors $\mathbf a_i$, $\mathbf b_i$ and $\mathbf c_i$ are linearly dependent.

Based on my elementary understanding of concepts like subspaces, dimensions, direct sums, etc., I feel this is true though I couldn't construct a satisfactory formal proof on my own.

---

We have that $A\cap B=\{\bf 0\}$ and that $\DeclareMathOperator{\dim}{dim}\dim A+\dim B=\dim\mathbb R^{2n}$. $\therefore \mathbb R^{2n}=A\bigoplus B\tag*{}$

Thus, every vector $\mathbf c_i$ in the basis $\{\mathbf{c}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of $C$ can be  uniquely represented as $\mathbf a_i'
+\mathbf b_i'$ for some vectors $\mathbf a_i'\in A$ and $\mathbf b_i'\in B$.

So that the given proposition is true, we need $\mathbf a_i'$ to be a scalar multiple of $\mathbf a_i$ and $\mathbf b_i'$ to be scalar multiple of $\mathbf b_i$.

I am not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: So you're left to show that $a'_i$ (resp $b'_i$) form a basis.  Which condition have you not applied? How could that be used?

Comment: @CalvinLin I think I didn't make use of the condition $A\cap C=B\cap C = \{\mathbf 0\}$. Your comment struck me... I guess I need to think more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think is a nice geometric view of this situation. If you have 3 subspaces with the properties you describe then you can think of the third one as a "graph" of the other two.

More precisely, you can show that for each $a\in A$ there is a unique $b\in B$ so that $a+b\in C$. You can see this a bit indirectly. Suppose you have a  two distinct points $c,c'\in C$ and you write them as $c=a+b$ and $c'=a'+b'$ where $a,a'\in A$ and $b,b'\in B$. Next, suppose that $a=a'$. Then $0\neq c-c'=b-b'$. This is a contradiction, since the $c-c'\in C$, $b-b'\in B$ and $B\cap C=0$. Thus $a\neq a'$. A similar argument shows that it must be the case that $b\neq b'$. What this shows is that each $c\in C$ determines a unique $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ and hence a map $M:A\to B$ where $M(a)$ is the unique element of $B$ so that $a+M(a)\in C$.

With a little bit of work you can show that $M$ is linear and injective, and hence an isomorphism. Now pick your favorite basis $\{a_1,\ldots, a_n\}$ of $A$, then $\{M(a_1),\ldots, M(a_n)\}$ is a basis of $B$ and $\{a_1+M(a_1),\ldots, a_n+M(a_n)\}$ is a basis of $C$. These bases will have the properties you want.

A good geometric picture to have in your head is three lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For instance, suppose $A$ is given by $y=0$ and $B$ is given by $x=0$ and $C$ is given by $y=dx$, then the map mentioned above is given by $(x,0)\mapsto $(0,dx)$.

Comment: Your solution is very satisfying!  Indeed, $M$ is linear because for all vectors $a_1+b_1$ and $a_2+b_2$ in $C$, the vector $a_1+\lambda a_2+b_1+\lambda b_2$ is also in $C$. It's injective because the kernel is trivial... There is only one vector in $C$ which is of the form $0+b$ and that is $0$ itself... Amazing! $\\$ I have thought of another mapping $N:A\to C$ such that $N(a)=a+M(a)$ which is also an isomorphism...

Answer (score 1):

Pushing through OP's approach

- OP starts with a (any) basis $\{ c_i \}$ of $C$.
- OP shows that there is a unique $a_i \in A, b_i \in B$ such that $a_i + b_i = c_i$.
- As pointed out in the comments, we just have to show that $\{a_i \}$ (resp $\{b_i\}$) form a basis for $A$ (resp $B$).

  - Proof by contradiction.
  - Suppose there is a (WLOG) $a_1 = \sum _{i=2}^n \alpha_i a_i$.
  - Then, with $ \alpha_1 = - 1$, we have $\sum \alpha_i c_i = \sum \alpha_i a_i + \sum \alpha_i b_i  = \sum \alpha_i  b_i$.
  - Since  $ B \cap C = \{0\}$, the above vector is the 0 vector. -> This is where we use the remaining condition of the problem.
  - This contradicts the assumption that $ c_i$ is a basis for $C$, since we have $ 0 = \sum \alpha_i c_i$.

Comment: If I understood the approach correctly, we first assume that, if possible, $\{a_i\}$ is linearly dependent (which also covers the instances of vectors being repeated) so there exists scalars $\alpha_i$'s in $\mathbb R$ (not all zero) such that $\sum \alpha_ia_i=0$. And then we use the fact that $c_i=a_i+b_i$ for each $i$ to get that $\sum \alpha_ic_i=\sum\alpha_ib_i$ which is just zero (because $B\cap C=\{0\}$). This is a contradiction of the fact that $\{c_i\}$ is a basis. I think, we also need to show that $\{b_i\}$ is linearly independent as well where we would use the fact $A\cap C=\{0\}$.

Comment: @Nothingspecial  Yup. The "(resp $\{b_i\}$)" is meant to indicate we have to repeat the argument for a change of coordinates.